# How to load and use XML in jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I am using the below code to use xml loading in jsfiddle.net

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "/echo/note.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml) {
        alert('Hi');       
   }
  });
```

But it is not working.. Please have a look at this and correct my mistakes..
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/RT9WL/6/) is the fiddle

Comment: `/echo/note.xml` doesn't exist.  Use Firebug/Chrome's debug tools.  You'd see a 404 error.

Comment: Also, please read [jsFiddle's docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#xml).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/GwGrG/

And the docs:

http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: @PrathapReddySV: Because the docs say the XML echo only works if you POST data to it.

Comment: @PrathapReddySV ... Because the docs say it must be a POST request, and the `xml` data should be well-formed XML. If neither are true, it won't work.

Comment: @d n Why this code does not work in my website when I use like this $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml",
    data: {
        xml: '<true/>'
    },
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        alert('Hi');
    }
});

Comment: @PrathapReddySV Cross-domain, it may not respond to a POST, it may not know what to do with your request data (the xml), who knows. What's your JavaScript console say?

Comment: It does not return any message :-(

Comment: @PrathapReddySV I find it unlikely there's nothing available in the JavaScript console or the request/response view in Chrome/Firebug/etc. But you're trying to use the documentation for one particular site to get data for another--that doesn't make any sense. At the very least, you likely want a GET request, and no data.

Comment: @PrathapReddySV: My example only works for jsFiddle because that's that their API wants.  Also, you can't just load arbitrary websites via JavaScript, you can only load things from your own domain.  It's called the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: I'm confused ... I do not see a url that you are requesting info from ... the whole point of ajax is to get info from a server ... in this example you are hardcoding an xml string into the data object: `xml: "<the>xml</the>"` ... ... thanks.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd ... The URL is where it says `url`. The data is what's being *sent*. The data *sent* is echoed back, hence the name "echo". I'm going to guess you didn't read the *second* link.

Comment: my understanding from that 2nd link is that `url: "/echo/xml/"`  is a literal directive that fiddle will read ... I did not realize I was supposed to replace it with an actual url.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd It's not a "literal directive", it's a relative URL.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Also, be wary of two-year old links and anders. In this case I suspect it's still correct, but still. Terri years is a lifetime.

Comment: so forgive me, but are we supposed to LEAVE the `url: "/echo/xml/"` as is, or are we supposed to replace the `"/echo/xml/"` with `http://www.my_server.com/my_ajax_url.php` ... ... if the former is true, then where do we input `http://www.my_server.com/my_ajax_url.php`??? .... .... if I am being stupid, please forgive me.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd The URL should be the URL of whatever you're getting data from. But AFAICR it won't work in jsfiddle, if that's what you're asking. If that's not what you're asking, the jQuery docs will be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the contents of the echo request. See the docs:

http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Here is the example code thanks to @Rocket.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/xml/",
    data: {
        xml: '<true/>'
    },
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        alert('Hi');
    }
});
```

Comment: @rocket When i am using in my website I am using like below  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
alert('hi');
}
</script> But it is not working :-( Why...

Comment: w3schools.com/xml/note.xml doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, Its there.. I can see the content also

Comment: The above code is not working when I am using it in my Website

Comment: There are two problems. 1) you have an extra semicolon after the url 2) you are trying to do a cross domain request which isn't allowed. If you run that code from jsfiddle with the console open you see this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://w3schools.com/xml/note.xml. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @PrathapReddySV: It's called the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You can't just load arbitrary websites via JavaScript, you can only load things from your own domain.